# Battery Power Management PCB Design

Tags: power, power-electronics, battery-operated, poe

I am working on an old PCB that uses a lot of the TI IC's for performing its functions.

It's essentially a power management board that takes a DC input and charges 12 batteries connected to the circuit. It has a power on/off button and a status LED light to show the overall battery level. It's a really old design. Instead of reverse engineering this I would now like to prepare an alternate design with similar or better functionality. Basically, to power networking devices over PoE. So the board must have at least 5 PoE ports and be able to power a load of 15W for up to 80 hours. This should be enough to help us narrow down on the battery capacity and requirements.

Wondering if anyone has any tips on how to get started on a circuit like this? I did robotics and specialized on the software side and wish I paid more attention in my electronic classes as well but it's never too late to learn and would appreciate all the help I can get to help make building a circuit that achieves or exceeds this.

Comment: I think the first step would be to read the "Art of Electronics"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, this question is a bit obtuse. We can't design stuff for you, please start on the design and then ask questions when you get stuck. If your trying to replace a product, then you've got to reverse engineer it first, understand exactly what each part of the circuit does and then you can find better circuits to replace older sections. As it stands this question is too broad

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you go to TIs website (or to other similar manufacturers) and look for [battery charging ICs](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/battery-charger-ic-products.page). They normally have typical application circuits that could help you understand what needs to be done and how you could achieve this.

The same for the [PoE ports](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/power-over-ethernet-overview.page). There are normally specialized regulators for this application.

Additionally study application notes that normally accompany the ICs.

Also study the existing circuit (of course only if a schematic is available, otherwise it could be challenging) and try to understand how it was implemented.

I would say more or less you need the following:
- A conversion of the input power source to a voltage that can be used on the board (for example an AC to DC converter and/or further step-down converters).
- Then battery charging ICs that take care of the actual charging process.
- PoE regulators that provide power to the PoE ports.